# unable to merge dex android studio

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

This is my Gradle file and it gives unable to merge dex error and cant run my app can any one solve it please???????I'm trying to run my project, but for some reason it gives me that error

Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformDexArchiveWithExternalLibsDexMergerForDebug'. com.android.builder.dexing.DexArchiveMergerException: Unable to merge dex

```
    apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 27
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.ahmed.farid.gonerve"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 27
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        multiDexEnabled true
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    //noinspection GradleCompatible
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1'

    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'

    //Design library for Coordinator Layout and Toolbars
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:27.1.1'

    //BottomNavigationViewEx library
    implementation 'com.github.ittianyu:BottomNavigationViewEx:1.2.4'
    //Circle ImageView
    implementation 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:2.1.0'
    //Universal image loader
    implementation 'com.nostra13.universalimageloader:universal-image-loader:1.9.5'
    implementation 'com.github.danylovolokh:video-player-manager:0.2.0'
    implementation 'com.google.code.findbugs:jsr305:2.0.1'
    implementation 'uk.co.chrisjenx:calligraphy:2.3.0'
    implementation 'com.rengwuxian.materialedittext:library:2.1.4'
    implementation 'com.firebase:geofire-android:2.1.1'
    implementation 'com.github.glomadrian:MaterialAnimatedSwitch:1.1@aar'
    //Design library for Coordinator Layout and Toolbars
    //BottomNavigationViewEx library
    implementation'com.android.support:cardview-v7:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.google.guava:guava:27.0-android'
    //noinspection GradleCompatible
    //firebase
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:11.0.2'
    //firebase auth
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:11.0.2'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:11.0.2'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:11.0.2'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:11.0.2'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:11.0.2'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:11.0.2'
    implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:3.7.0'

    implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:27.1.1'

}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this in

**android/build.gradle**

```
android {
    defaultConfig {
       multiDexEnabled true
    }
}
```